# Sampling from Gaussian with very large covariance matrix in block form

Tags: algorithms, normal-distribution, covariance, sampling

I'm interested in sampling from a Gaussian with zero-mean and covariance given by:
$$
\Sigma = \begin{bmatrix}
\Sigma_{11} & \Sigma_{12} & \cdots &\Sigma_{1,100}\\
\Sigma_{21} & \Sigma_{22} & \cdots &\Sigma_{2,100}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \cdots &\vdots \\
\Sigma_{100,1} & \Sigma_{100,2} & \cdots &\Sigma_{100,100}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $\Sigma_{ij}$ is a square matrix of dimension $p \times p$. In words, the covariance matrix is massive and I am not able to load the entire array into memory. Are there any approaches that allow me to sample from such a Gaussian but only access a subset of the blocks at a time?

Comment: There is the [standard method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Drawing_values_from_the_distribution) but that just begs the question: how to do the Cholesky decomposition. Will you allow yourself to resort to approximations such as PCA?

Comment: @BenjaminWang yes, i didn't mention it in my post but if there is a way to compute the cholesky here that would be sufficient to solve my problem. I think PCA is worth a shot, but also not really sure how to do PCA here either..

Comment: If the covariance is low rank, you can use a [randomized svd](https://gregorygundersen.com/blog/2019/01/17/randomized-svd/) or similar algorithm to find a low rank decomposition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Cholesky–Banachiewicz and Cholesky–Crout algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition#The_Cholesky%E2%80%93Banachiewicz_and_Cholesky%E2%80%93Crout_algorithms). They allow you to calculate each row of the Cholesky decomposition while using only one row from $\Sigma$ at a time.